# Have someone do/doing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1- We ***had a man singing*** to us as we sat in the restaurant having
>   our meal.
>
> 2- We ***had a strange woman come*** to the door selling pictures.
>
> 3- I just ***had them doing*** stretch routines, and after, they got
>   really good at it.
>
> 4- A: Is there running water? B: Of course, there is running water. B:
>   Oh, but I wouldn't use it. It is very contaminated. We ***had three
>   dogs die*** in the well.
>
> 5- I ***have half the Committee coming*** tonight.

What is the difference between "have someone do" and "have someone doing" ?

Answer (score 1):

Phrases you mentioned in **present continuous** do describe an ongoing action, but the phrases with **have someone do** in present  didn't refer to an ongoing action.

You may ask how about the 5th phrase, you can use present continuous for future plans, like below:

- what are you doing this weekend ?
- I am playing soccer this weekend
- I am working this Saturday.
- I am visiting tonight

Comment: I just don't understand which version to use in appropriate context. For example: Why does sentence 1 use continuous form while sentence 2 uses infinitive form?

Comment: @Talha - Because they were written that way. There's no reason we couldn't say: _We had a man **sing** to us as we sat in the restaurant having our meal._ Or: _We had a strange woman **coming** to the door selling pictures._ It's not like one version is correct and the other is wrong; it's more about slightly different nuances. Did the woman come to the door to sell just once, or over and over again? If just once, we'd probably use _come_, but if it was over and over again, we might use _coming_.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. Can we use infinitive form in the sentence 5 since "coming tonight" is a one-time event.

Comment: @Talha - Sentence 5 is fine as is.